# Convert inputs to arrays in julia

Tags: numpy, julia

Is there an alternative to `numpy.atleast_2d()` in Julia.

The python function can be found on this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-atleast_2d-in-python/

Comment: I have not heard of such a function, but you can just write: `ndims(x) == 1 ? reshape(x, :, 1) : x`

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the Python Numpy docs this needs to be defined as:

```
atleast_2d(a) = fill(a,1,1)
atleast_2d(a::AbstractArray) = ndims(a) == 1 ? reshape(a, :, 1) : a
```

Testing:

```
julia> atleast_2d(3)
1×1 Matrix{Int64}:
 3

julia> atleast_2d([4,5])
2×1 Matrix{Int64}:
 4
 5
```